# How to cut up vegetables and fruit for horses

Tags: health, feeding, safety, horses, treats

Horses can choke on chunks of vegetables like carrot or sweet potato.

To be clear - when horses suffer choke - it does not mean the food goes down the wrong pipe. It means the food is lodged in the oesophagus and will not shift. This can press on the windpipe if severe enough, but usually what will happen if the horse cannot resolve the choke, the horse will be unable to eat or drink and will die of dehydration. Saliva may also slip into the trachea and cause pneumonia.

How should vegetables and fruit be cut up in a way to minimise the risk of choking in horses?

Related: [What treats are safe for horses?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/15464/what-treats-are-safe-for-horses)

Answer (score 1):

Another try...

I searched for sources for avoiding choking of gullet of horses. In Germany there is a central organisation called "FN" for all activities one could do with horses.

Their [homepage](https://www.pferd-aktuell.de/ausbildung/pferdehaltung/pferdefuetterung/verdauungsapparat-und-folgen-falscher-fuetterung) about feeding and feeding errors show this (via Google translator)

> **pharyngeal blockages**
>
> Life-threatening!
>
> Throat blockages are caused by feeding swellable, but not soaked feed (e.g. beet pulp), hasty swallowing of the crib feed (insufficient salivation), pieces of fruit and vegetables that are not chewed. Therefore: Any feed that continues to swell when hydrated must be soaked before feeding! First feed hay, then feed oats! Hay or straw chopped into the crib feed slows down the feeding speed and ensures more thorough chewing. Do not cut fruit and vegetables into small pieces before feeding!

I guess sweet potatoes are near beets fruits, so maybe the swell-ability played a role at your experience.

Like you could read: they guess to NOT cut fruits and vegetable into any pieces.

Comment: This may give better advice - I don't know if you want to include this in your answer. https://equusmagazine.com/diseases/choke-risk `Break down hard treats, such as apples and carrots, into pieces no larger than your thumb`

Comment: @YvetteHorsewoman it is funny for me because I do not understand. Did you change you mind because of the sources or did not we understand us in my first answer? There I wrote: cut them very small or let them in whole and let the horse bite the right amount of it...

Comment: I literally wanted a size of safety to cut them up. For example - if they are cut into the wrong size - they may be just big enough to get stuck if not swallowed - what is that size.

Comment: I have no source for it. But I would cut them in size like a candy. Thumb size seems for my feeling big. I would cut the "thumb" in half. But without source...

Comment: I agree re the thumb - I'm a woman and my fingers are fairly slim, so a thumb size would not be so bad. I think carrot sticks - like for dip is good . You didn't need to delete the other answer. You could have left it and edited it. I would have reversed the downvote - for future reference.